# When I save a CSS file in Sublime it shows an alert daying i need to get Node.js

Tags: html, css, sublimetext

I got onto my laptop this morning to program and I opened sublime, started editing and pressed CTRL+S (Save) and it showed this error:

[image]

I am just wondering, what does that mean? Just something more, I am using MX Linux and I am saving directly to a USB stick, which is plugged in and mounted.

Thanks,

Ring Games Office

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something that Sublime is doing, it's something that a package that you installed is doing, in this case the [CSSOrder](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSSOrder) package; the text of the error message indicates that it is CSSOrder that's generating the message.

The link to the package above shows you the README for the package, which has installation instructions for the package:

[image: Package installation instructions]

The error message is stating the problem directly; it needs to use NodeJS in order to execute the scripts that the package requires, but it can't find NodeJS. As a result, it's not able to do anything.

Installing NodeJS may make the problem go away; uninstalling the package definitely will since it can't do anything without NodeJS anyway.

If NodeJS is already installed, then it's not in the `$PATH` and can't be found. This particular package provides no configuration option for locating Node. In order for the plugin to find it, you must be able to enter `node` at a terminal or command prompt and have it find and run `node`.

How you add things to the path depends on the OS you're using as well as the version of that OS and other various properties (on Linux, what shell you're using). If you're unsure of how to do this, do a search for how to add items to the path on your particular combination and version of OS to determine how to do it.